# Use content script in custom chrome extension page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension i have an extra page, that is open via

```
window.open(chrome.extension.getURL("manager.html"));
```

On that page i would like to use some functions of my content script. But it seems the content script is not loaded at all on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply include your scripts to the extra page using `<script>` tags.